Blazor web app (Linux hosting): The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')
Current setup

Blazor Web App (interactive server)
.Net 8 runtime
Zip deployment into azure web app
Azure web app operating system is linux

The issue
So after starting the azure web app I can see following exception in the log stream:
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.<>c.<UseStaticWebAssetsCore>b__1_0(String contentRoot)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider..ctor(StaticWebAssetManifest manifest, Func`2 fileProviderFactory)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssetsCore(IWebHostEnvironment environment, Stream manifest)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ConfigureWebHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(Action`2 configureDelegate)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseStaticWebAssets(IWebHostBuilder builder)
at MyWebApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\src\MyWebApp\Program.cs:line 28

I did add the line
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

as this fixed another issue I had before, where the web app could not load any file from wwwroot directory.
What I have already tried
I did try and set WebApplicationOptions manually, giving a value for "WebRootPath":
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = @"C:\home\site\wwwroot"
});

Idea was to give a rooted path as I did have a look into the implementation of UseStaticWebAssets() and saw that there is a check called Path.IsPathRooted(root), checking for a path starting with backslash or a local drive name (e.g. C:). But that caused the exception:
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/site/wwwroot/C:\home\site\wwwroot' is denied.

which makes sense as the path is absolutely weird. I have also observed that the args parameter from main function:
void Main(string[] args)
is empty. I am not sure if this behavior is correct as we give the args as parameter into the CreateBuilder function:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
I also published my blazor app into a web app hosted on windows and there the app runs fine without any issue.
Updates on comments
My zip file is created in a build pipeline (based on yaml file) and released via release pipeline in azure devops.
My wwwroot folder contains only one stylesheet and one javascript file.
Questions

Why do I get the exception: The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root') in a linux hosted web app?
What is the difference in hosting on linux and windows with regards to run the app?
If the root parameter have to be set, how do I do that?


Are you using nginx server for hosting your app?

No, I do not think so. While creating the Web App in azure i can only choose how to publish (Code), runtime stack (.Net 8), operating system (Linux) and the region.

This error maybe occurs because of wwwroot folder doesn't exists or incorrect path & you are trying to access wwwroot folder.

Hi @rekcul Why you hard code C:\home\site\wwwroot for your WebRootPath? For linux, there is no C: disk.

@rekcul May I know how you deploy the webapp via zip, I will write a tutorial below for you, please wait 10 min.

@JasonPan that was just a try to see how the app reacts when overriding the WebRootPath manually. I agree, C: does not really make sense, but having a look into the exception it caused, it seems like the WebRootPath is only appended to the existing "/home/site/wwwroot/" path. I did expect that it will replace the path completely.

@AbhayDedkawala so it definitely exists in my solution/csproj. How can I ensure that it exists in the web app in azure? How to set the correct path?

What I mean is that we don't need to worry about the path at all. If there is a problem during startup, it is probably related to the release, so you need to go through the steps of the release process in detail and try again.

Could you share what files are under wwwroot?

@JasonPan I use a azure devops release pipeline, deploying the blazor web app artifact (zip) that was created by a build pipeline (based on yaml).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After using below steps, we can narrow down the scope of this problem and find out whether the problem occurs in the azure webapp or in the publishing process.
Here is the detailed steps.
Step 1.  Create a webapp in azure portal.
Step 2.  Create a brand new blazor web app in VS2022.
Step 3.  Publish it to folder.

Step 4.  Compress the content as zip file.

Step 5.  Open the advance tool in azure portal, and append the /newui in the url.

Step 6.  Navgatigate to wwwroot folder and drag the zip file.

Step 7.  Add the startup command.
After deployment, if we can find the content like below, it means the we have deply the project successfully.

